# How to use paper_trail with carrierwave (for undo support)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undo, carrierwave

I'm trying to include undo support using the `paper_trail` gem and the tutorial described in this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail.

The thing is that my model also uses `carrierwave` for pictures manipulation. After deleting an instance of the model, the picture also gets deleted. Is there any way to prevent that and restore the instance of the model using `paper_trail` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't delete the file, just delete the reference to it (database entry). Or, if you need the space, mark it for deletion and have a cron job run to delete the file at a later time.

You could also put the file in the database, but because of the way paper trail versions, this has the potential for taking up significantly more space.

Comment: Agree with your first statement. My problem is how do I do that ? Calling `@model.destroy` deletes the file, I can't seem to figure out what should I call on the model that doesn't delete the file as well.

Comment: You could try doing `my_object.delete` to skip the Active Record callbacks that run when calling `destroy`. But I'd advise you ask on the [Carrierwave Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/carrierwave) to see if there's an option to skip just that, or, if not, open an issue requesting so on Github.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the clean way of doing this?